# React Native: Prevent screen from being turned off while coding

Tags: android, react-native

I created react-native project using `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`, When I run(debug) my app in android device (`yarn android`) after sometime my device screen getting turned off (while I'm coding and connected to laptop).

Every time when I do a code change I need to turned on device screen to see the change.

How to prevent this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Developer settings on the device there is an option to keep the screen on when connected to a computer.

Comment: To be more specific: Settings -> Developer options -> Stay awake (or Stay awake while charging or Stay awake while usb debugging)